# Find the occurence of events

Tags: pandas

I have an array with five different events, each event occurs for different intervals more than one time.

Ex:.

```
array(['walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'Running', 'Running',
       'Running', 'Running', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking',
       'walking', 'Standing', 'Standing', 'Standing', 'walking', 'walking',
       'walking'], dtype='<U8')
```

.... (3245 long)

I want to extract an array for each event that indicates the intervals for each event.

The results should be as the following for the example above:

```
Walking_occurence = [
(0,3),
(8,12),
(16,18)
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a potential approach using [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(['walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'Running',
              'Running', 'Running', 'Running', 'walking', 'walking',
              'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'Standing', 'Standing',
              'Standing', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking'])

s = pd.Series(a)

s_out = ((s != s.shift()).cumsum().reset_index()
          .groupby([0, s])['index']
          .agg(['min', 'max'])
          .apply(tuple, axis=1))

# print(s_out)
# 1  walking       (0, 3)
# 2  Running       (4, 7)
# 3  walking      (8, 12)
# 4  Standing    (13, 15)
# 5  walking     (16, 18)
```

You could then do a further groupby opperation to get your desired results:

```
s_out = s_out.groupby(level=1, sort=False).apply(np.array)
```

[out]

```
walking     [(0, 3), (8, 12), (16, 18)]
Running                        [(4, 7)]
Standing                     [(13, 15)]
dtype: object
```

Comment: now i got it what he actual wants, in this case my solution is completely different, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I took your list of activities as a plain *Python* list:

```
act = ['walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'running', 'running',
    'running', 'running', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking',
    'standing', 'standing', 'standing', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking']
```

Then the steps to perform are as follows:

1. `import itertools` (will be needed soon).
2. Create a DataFrame from *act*:

   ```
   df = pd.Series(act).to_frame(name='activity')
   ```
3. Generate data to an auxiliary DataFrame:

   ```
   rows = []
   for k, g in itertools.groupby(df.itertuples(name='row'), lambda row: row.activity):
       grp = list(g)
       rows.append([(grp[0].Index, grp[-1].Index), k])
   ```

   Note that *itertools.groupby* differs from *Pandas* version of *groupby* in one
   detail: Each change in the key of the source element opens a new group.

   So the result is:

   ```
   [[(0, 3), 'walking'],
    [(4, 7), 'running'],
    [(8, 12), 'walking'],
    [(13, 15), 'standing'],
    [(16, 18), 'walking']]
   ```
4. Create the auxiliary DataFrame:

   ```
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['id', 'activity'])
   ```
5. Generate the final result:

   ```
   df2.groupby('activity').id.agg(list)
   ```

The result is:

```
activity
running                        [(4, 7)]
standing                     [(13, 15)]
walking     [(0, 3), (8, 12), (16, 18)]
Name: id, dtype: object
```

E.g. for *walking* - **one** list of (*from*, *to*) tuples, just as you want.